# Conditional Update to change same column in SQL

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

```
id  name    status

1   abc 1
2   pqr 0
```

conditional update for same column

I want query like

update table 
 set status = 1
 Where id = 2 
AND 
  set status = 0
  Where id != 2

is it possible to do with single query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE <table>
SET status = (CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 1
                   ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Thanks , It Works can u help me how to write in zendframe work

Comment: @zuberSurya Use `Zend_Db_Expr`

Answer (score 1):

```
update table set status = CASE id WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```